# Find the direction of maximum decrease of the function $g$ in the point $(1,1)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let be $g(x, y)=f\left(x^{2}+y, 3 x y\right),$ where $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function. Assume that the gradient of $f$ in (2,3) is the vector  $5 \hat{\mathbf{i}}+4 \hat{\mathbf{j}} .$ Find the direction of maximum decrease of the function $g$ in the point $(1,1)$

I don't know exactly what I have to do.
I know g :$\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ because $f$ is a function $\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$
I and I know that the maximum decrease is the opposite to the gradient but how can I know what is $f$ any hint?

Comment: Hint: chain rule

Comment: @Miguel Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find the gradient of $g$ at $(1,1)$. Take $u=x^2+y,v=3xy$, then$$\begin{align*}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x}\\\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}_{x=1\\y=1}&=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial x}\\\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}_{u=2\\v=3}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\\\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}_{x=1,y=1\\u=2,v=3}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}2x\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}+3y\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial v}\\\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}+3x\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial v}\end{bmatrix}_{x=1,y=1\\u=2,v=3}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}2\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}+3\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial v}\\\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}+3\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial v}\end{bmatrix}_{u=2\\v=3}\end{align*}$$Now you are given $$\nabla f(u,v)=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}\\\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial v}\end{bmatrix}_{u=2\\v=3}=[5,4]^T$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes of course it will be $[2(5)+3(4),5+3(4)]=[22,17]$ just one question why the gradient of $g$ in $(1,1)]$ is equal to gradient of $f$ in $(2,3)$ is because $g(1,1)=f(2,3)$ right?

Comment: NO! $g(1,1)=f(2,3)$ but the gradient of $g$ at $(1,1)$ is **not** identical to gradient of $f$ at $(2,3)$. The former is $[22,17]^T$, the latter is $[5,4]^T$. If you are satisfied with my answer, consider accepting it by clicking the tick-mark button next to it.

Comment: @KevinDuran You might be getting confused by the first equation. Note on the LHS is the gradient of $g$ but on the RHS is not the gradient of $f$, check the partial differential carefully.